# In JQuery how do I get the DIV that the mouseover/mouseenter came from?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the div that the mouse was previously on before it entered the element.

How do I get this in JQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. I got it.

```
console.log(e.fromElement.className);
```